Geometrically interpreting the derivative of a parametric function being orthogonal to the parametric function
The following is exercise 6.A.33 of Linear Algebra Done Right, fourth edition, Sheldon Axler:

Suppose $f, g$ are differentiable functions from $\mathbf{R}$ to $\mathbf{R}^n$.
(a) Show that
$$
\langle f(t), g(t) \rangle ' = \langle f'(t), g(t) \rangle  + \langle f(t), g'(t) \rangle .
$$
(b) Suppose $c$ is a positive number and $\left\lVert f(t) \right\rVert = c$ for every $t \in \mathbf{R}$. Show that $\langle f'(t), f(t) \rangle = 0$ for every $t \in \mathbf{R}$.
(c) Interpret the result in (b) geometrically in terms of the tangent vector to a curve lying on a sphere in $\mathbf{R}^n$ centered at the origin.

I've already done part (a) and part (b), but based on my reading of this wiki page, I have the following questions:
Question 1.
In part (b), we're assuming $\left\lVert f(t) \right\rVert = c$ for every $t \in \mathbf{R}$. Does this mean that we're able to trace out a sphere with a radius of $c$? If so, are we defining this sphere in $\mathbf{R}^n$ as
$$
S^{n-1} := \{f(t) \in \mathbf{R}^n : \left\lVert f(t) \right\rVert = c, \ \ \forall t \in \mathbf{R}\}
$$
Question 2.
When the hypothesis in part (b) is satisfied, we get that $\langle f'(t), f(t) \rangle = 0$ for every $t \in \mathbf{R}$. This means that $f'(t)$ is orthogonal to $f(t)$.
I'm trying to understand how this would look like in $\mathbf{R}^2$. Is the following illustration representative of the above?

Question 3.
In terms of part (c), what does it mean for a curve to lie on the above circle? And how would the tangent vector look like -- is it attached to the point $(f_1(t), f_2(t))$? In what direction is it going?


No, this is just a (differentiable) path lying on the sphere. Indeed, if $f$ is continuously differentiable, then it cannot possibly fill up the sphere.

Yes, the picture is correct.

Yes, you should think of the tangent line to the curve, passing through the point $f(t)$. The direction of that line is given by the vector $f'(t)$, and the radius vector (i.e., $f(t)$) is orthogonal to that line because $\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle = 0$.


By the way, this result is extremely important in physics and in the differential geometry of curves and surfaces (see, e.g., p. 10 of my differential geometry text, freely linked in my profile).

Thank you, Ted! I especially appreciate the particle example you give in the remark after the proof in your text.

You’re most welcome. You might also find some of my YouTube lectures on multivariable analysis and linear algebra helpful.
